# Adding my logs (values) to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Okay so I'm making logs of some distance variables
- example;

```
loghospital=log(hospital_2015_distance, base=exp(1))
```

Works, i get values that i can run in a regression.

However for my LASSO regression it's better i specify a dataset.
So i want a dataframe of these logs (values).

Or better I want these logs (values) added to my existing dataframe called (data).

Any idea how this can be achieved? And if not, what else i should do to achieve the same?

Comment: `data$loghospital=log(hospital_2015_distance, base=exp(1))` adds it as a column in `data`.

Comment: Your probably getting downvoted for not showing more research effort (What di you find in your Google search, etc.).

Comment: what is simple for one is hard for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add it to your `data.frame` you can use `$`:

```
data$loghospital = log(hospital_2015_distance, base=exp(1))
```

Also you could use `[[` or `[` and probably should `<-` instead of `=` for assignment:

```
# Examples:
data[["loghospital"]] <- log(hospital_2015_distance, base=exp(1))
data["loghospital"]   <- log(hospital_2015_distance, base=exp(1))
data[, "loghospital"] <- log(hospital_2015_distance, base=exp(1))
```